# How to get caret position inside any application using Java?

Tags: java, position, caret

It seemed to be such a simple question, but after a long time researching the topic, I am still not able to find any answer to this.
Using Java, I want to display a small tooltip next to a caret (text cursor) position.

I need to caret position inside any application.
That means if I open Word, Notepad, Chrome browser and I start typing I need to see X & Y of the cursor.

Any way to do this using Java?
I've seen implementations in C# on CodeProject, but I need to do this in java.

Comment: I'm not sure that this possible (certainly isn't from within Java, you will need some kind of JNA/JNI integration) from a native level

Comment: Okay, apparently, under windows, you might...[GUITHREADINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632604(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: And if you don't mind translating from C#, you could [look at this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34520/Getting-Caret-Position-Inside-Any-Application)

Comment: Thans MadProgrammer, I'll look into GUITHREADINFO, but I need my application to be compatible with other operating systems, not only Windows. 
Does anyone know of any JNA/JNI integration?

Answer (score -2):

Basically use the .getMagicCaretPosition() function:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.text.Caret;
public class CaretPos implements Runnable
{
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextPane tPane;
    Caret newCaret;
    Point point;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("CaretPos");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        tPane = new JTextPane();
        newCaret = tPane.getCaret(); // you probably dont need to create another
                                     // Caret, but i did anyway to add the listener
        newCaret.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                point = newCaret.getMagicCaretPosition();
                System.out.println(point);
            }
        });
        tPane.setCaret(newCaret);
        tPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        panel.add(tPane);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CaretPos run = new CaretPos();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(run);
    }

}
```

I used a JTextPane, but im sure other swing components can be used

EDIT: Sorry I totally misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to find the caret
position in ANY of YOUR programs. My bad.